# Why does my list.append not permanently add my item?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

When I add an item to my list, it gets removed next time I add another item.

```
food_choice = str(input("Do you want to add an item, remove an item or  search for a recipes? "))
food = []
if food_choice in ["Add", "add"]:
    food_to_add = str(input("Which item would you like to add? "))
    food.append(food_to_add)
    print(food_to_add, "has been addded to your fridge list.")
    print(food)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialise your list before you repeatedly add items. The natural way to achieve this is to wrap your logic in a `while` loop and add an option to end the loop, e.g. keyword "end".

Otherwise, as in your code, `food = []` will initialise a new empty list each time.

```
food = []

while True:
    food_choice = str(input("Do you want to add, remove, search, or end? "))

    if food_choice.lower() == 'end':
        break

    if food_choice.lower() == 'add':
        food_to_add = str(input("Which item would you like to add? "))
        food.append(food_to_add)
        print(food_to_add, "has been addded to your fridge list.")
        print(food)
```

Example usage:

```
Do you want to add, remove, search, or end? add
Which item would you like to add? banana
banana has been addded to your fridge list.
['banana']
Do you want to add, remove, search, or end? add
Which item would you like to add? orange
orange has been addded to your fridge list.
['banana', 'orange']
Do you want to add, remove, search, or end? end
```

Comment: @EliasFiz python doesn't have any magic to save variables to permanent storage. Variables only live until they are no longer needed. That includes the python interpreter being closed. If you want to retain data between runs, you must save and load data in a file.

Comment: @EliasFiz I am confident any beginner's guide to python will cover file I/O. And the [official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) does as well :)

Comment: @EliasFiz as long as you write the appropriate saving/loading code, sure.